# Can I call a javascript function in model of codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Can I call a javascript function in model of codeigniter?

I made a modal in my view..

```
<div class="modal fade" id="success" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-haspopup="true" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="alert alert-success fade in" id="alert">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4>Success!</h4>
                 <p>Record successfully deleted.</p>
                 <a id="okButton" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">
                     OK 
                 </a>
               </div>     
          </div>
     </div>
```

and in my model

```
public function delete_job_title($P1)
{
   if (success condition)
   {
      what could should i put in here to call the function in javascript? or to show the modal?
   }
}
```

I don't know what to put in there in order to show the modal?.                            whereas in jquery you can show it by:

" $('#success').modal('show'); "

but I want to call it in my model.

My main question is there a way to call a function in javascript from a model of codeigniter?

whereas in my javascript:

```
function showsuccess()
{
$('#success').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: what? modal is a hidden alert that you will call in jquery dude.

Comment: Exactly, dude. And model is a part of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and should never contain anything like jQuery.

Comment: how about in controller can i call my jquery function in there? like $this->jquery? or something?

Comment: No. CodeIgniter is a PHP framework. PHP is a server-side language. jQuery is a JavaScript 'framework', and JS is a client-side language. Everything that happens in the client should be in the view. Please take some time to learn more about PHP, JS, MVC...

Comment: ow im sorry. im just new in programming.

Comment: but ive seen something like $this->jquery->show();

Comment: Modal in CI is for working with database but jQuery modal window is different.

Comment: There are no modals in CI...
@user2789695 The code you've seen might be used to generate a script part in the view, probably in case you're doing some complex script building/retrieving script from the db/etc... But it still goes into the view...everything that goes to screen is in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only controller can interact with javascript/ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
<input type='button' name='show_model' class='modal_display'>
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('.modal_display').click(function(){
         $('.modal-content').load('controller/method');
    });
});
```